# ImportError: cannot import name 'start_chrome' from 'selenium'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am have no idea how selenium works. I just want to scrap data. Here is my code

```py
from helium import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium
from selenium import start_chrome
    
start_url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
    
new = start_chrome(url= start_url, headless=True)
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(new.page_source, 'html.parser')
    
quotes = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'quote'})
    
    
for item in quotes:
    print(item.find('span', {'class':'text'}))
```

I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Sarfi Projects\python\remaining_tasks\remaining_tasks\spiders\helium.py", line 1, in <module>
    from helium import *
  File "G:\Sarfi Projects\python\remaining_tasks\remaining_tasks\spiders\helium.py", line 4, in <module>
    from selenium import start_chrome
ImportError: cannot import name 'start_chrome' from 'selenium' (G:\Sarfi Projects\python\remaining_tasks\env\lib\site-packages\selenium\__init__.py)
```

Anyone can please help me. I am suffering from two days but getting same results

Answer (score 2):

There is no `start_chrome` module in `selenium` resource.
You should use this

```py
from selenium import webdriver
```

Example of working code is:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Hey @Prophet dear I tried this and now I am getting "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" Do you have any idea?

Comment: From code you shared I can't see that

Comment: Should I update this now...?

Comment: Have you tried my updated answer?

Comment: Yes I tried your code and getting `TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'. `

Comment: Seems like you did not try exactly  what I pasted here. This is a real code I use. I do not have This `WebDriver.__init__()` ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75173767/typeerror-webdriver-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-service here is the updated code that i try and i am getting the error please take look

Comment: I see. Again. There is no `WebDriver.__init__()` in my code. That means you did not copy exactly what I gave you

Comment: Dear I just copy of your code and pasted as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251267/discussion-between-sarfraz-and-prophet).

Comment: `start_chrome(url= start_url)` is from Helium. See the first import _`from helium import *`_

Answer (score 1):

To initialize [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) using [Helium](https://selenium-python-helium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) you need to:

```
from helium import *

start_url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
new = start_chrome(url= start_url, headless=True)
```

Note: You don't require the import `from selenium import start_chrome`

---

Incase you require `ChromeOptions` and `DesiredCapabilities` then you can:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
```

Comment: Hey dear I am new with selenium I don't have any idea how to use ChromeOptions and DesiredCapabilities . Can you please again help me to find the solution thanks

Comment: @Sarfraz `ChromeOptions` and `DesiredCapabilities` would come later. First check if you can initialize the Chrome browser and revert back to me.

Comment: Dear I just download chrome driver and initialize it

Comment: Dear I just read this doc . But I can't understand. I answer you as I receive notification